# update if exists otherwise insert

Tags: mysql

This is the table structure for a shopping cart

[image]

I want to insert a row if the new `user_id` and `product_id` combination do not exist in the table otherwise I want to update the `quantity` only if the combination exists. My intention is to update someone's shopping cart in the database and insert if there are new items.

For example, if I have these data already in the table
[image]

If I have these data group (1,23,5), it will only update the `quantity` in the first row as the combination (1,23) already exists
[image]

If I have these data group (1,38,1), a new row will be inserted as the combination (1,38) does not exist
[image]

Comment: aren't they a composite primary key?

Comment: Why not just make a unique key out of `user_id` and `product_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Define a unique index on the values that you do not want duplicated:

```
create unique index idx_shoppingcart_user_product on shoppingcart(userid, productid)
```

Then, duplicate of these *two* columns together are not allowed.  (Note:  you can also define this constraint using `unique` or `primary key` in `create table`.)

Then use `on duplicate key`:

```
insert into shoppingcart(user_id, product_id, quantity) 
    select . . . 
    on duplicate key update
        quantity = quantity + values(quantity);
```

Or, perhaps,

```
    on duplicate key update
        quantity = values(quantity);
```

Your question is vague on what you mean by "update the `quantity` only".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically. Or create a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO (
user_id INT,
product_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, product_id));
```